# Checking the status of the indicated file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2008

Could you tell me how to use C# to check if the indicated file on the Windows Server is currently used by another user with access to the server?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does not quite meet the standards that StackOverflow expects. Your question in its current state will likely not get accepted. I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use filewatcher, it will monitor a directory and you can filter the files you want to watch

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed?view=netframework-4.7.2